# Timout expired issue in database in C# and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

Right now I am facing time out issue in my web application when database perform update / insert operations on multiple tables.

Database size is 80 GB and I am wanting to resolve this time out issue from application level.

Can any one please help me to sort out this issue basis of below point -

1. Create new indexing in already running database

Thanks 
SS

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL comes with a default setting of 30 seconds to timeout a transaction. Adding an index to a 80GB database might take more then that.

To increate the timeout value, go to:

**Tools** > **Options** > **Designers** > **Table and Database Designers**

And increase its value.

[image]